# long text without break to wrap around float element

Tags: css, word-wrap

Is it possible to wrap a piece of long text around a floated element?

Currently I have an element floating to the right, and normal text wraps around it nicely. However even with `word-wrap: break-word` the long text would not wrap around the image.

https://jsfiddle.net/64pp4kmm/1/

CSS:

```
.right {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
div {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.comment {
    background-color: aqua;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class='comment'>
    <div class="right">
        like
    </div> verylongtextverylongtextverylongtextverylongtextverylongtextverylongtextverylongtextverylongtextverylongtextverylongtextverylong
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `word-break: break-all;` instead of `word-wrap`. Since it's such a long word, you want to `break` it, only if words are separated with spaces (similar to breaks) you'd want to `wrap` them around something. Something that isn't broken, can't be wrapped.

So your CSS will look like this:

```
.right {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
div {
    word-break: break-all;
}
.comment {
    background-color: aqua;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/64pp4kmm/2/)

More info on [word-break](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-break/).

Comment: Though I don't like word-break but I think this is the only way to wrap around floated element :)